# sort function definitions according to its size

Tags: regex, perl

I am getting function definitions sizes from a .C file and I have list of all functions definitions names in a text file

CODE

```
open(FILE, "< file.c") or die $!;                #source file
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

open(FILE2, "> file_function_size.txt") or die $!;

open(FILE1, "< functions.txt") or die $!;        #contains list of function names
chomp( my @functions = <FILE1> );
close(FILE1);

my $match_function = qr/\b(@{[ join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @functions ]})\([^;]+$/;
my %function_size;
my $function = '';
for my $source_line (@lines) {
    if ( $source_line =~ $match_function ) {
        $function = $1;
        $function_size{$function} = 0;
    }
    elsif ( $source_line =~ /^}/ ) {
        $function = '';
    }
    # ignore first {
    elsif ( $function && ( $source_line !~ /^{/ || $function_size{$function} ) ) {
        ++$function_size{$function};
    }
}

for my $function (@functions) {
    if ( exists $function_size{$function} ) {
        print FILE2 "Function $function has $function_size{$function} lines.\n";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT I GET IS

```
Function ChainCtrlBuildChain has 63 lines.
Function ChainCtrlDumpChain has 22 lines.
Function ChainCtrlExit has 6 lines.
Function ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan has 36 lines.
```

**I want to sort it according to its size**

```
Function ChainCtrlExit has 6 lines.
Function ChainCtrlDumpChain has 22 lines.
Function ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan has 36 lines.
Function ChainCtrlBuildChain has 63 lines.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing printing loop as follows

```
foreach my $function (sort {$function_size{$a} <=> $function_size{$b}} keys %function_size) {
    print FILE2 "Function $function has $function_size{$function} lines.\n";
}
```

It will numerically sort keys of %function_size according to its values i.e. size.

Comment: @Ad-vic you're welcome. glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special function like this:

```
sub by_size {
    $a =~ /Function \s+ has (\d+\) lines./;
    my $a_lines = $1;
    $b =~ /Function \s+ has (\d+\) lines./;
    my $b_lines = $1;

    return $a_lines <=> $b_lines;
}

@sorted_output = sort by_size @output;
```

This assumes that `@output` contains strings of the format:

```
Function ChainCtrlBuildChain has 63 lines.
Function ChainCtrlDumpChain has 22 lines.
Function ChainCtrlExit has 6 lines.
Function ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan has 36 lines.
```

### Explanation:

This line tells `sort` to use the `by_size` function for sorting:

```
@sorted_output = sort by_size @output;
```

The `by_size` function has 2 inputs: global variables called `$a` and `$b`. These are passed to it by `sort`.

This function processes `$a` and `$b` and returns a value of `1`, `0` or `-1` meaning:

- `-1` --> `$a` comes before `$b`
- `0` --> `$a` is equal to `$b` for the purposes of this sorting.
- `1` --> `$a` comes after `$b`

In this specific case, `by_size` determines the order by extracting the number of lines from the strings `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: thanks for explanation. both the answers works fine. But i am checking the first one as its bit small and simpler and the answer came first.

Comment: But you provided better logic to the problem. I understood it. thanks